# "strcpy()" está mesclando formato numérico com outros chars

Tags: c, array, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Eu não sei se consegui me fazer entender no título, mas ao usar `strcpy()` para copiar um `char*` para outro quando coloco um formato assim `"teste"` ele funciona normalmente, mas quando coloco uma *string* com formato 3 letras (dígitos no caso), por exemplo `"2000"` ele acaba mesclando esse valor para o destino com o próximo valor da próxima vez que uso `strcpy()`, segue o código:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char nome[80];
    char ano[4];
    char diretor[80];
} Filme;

void analise(Filme *filme, const char *arg1, const char *arg2, const char *arg3)
{
    Filme _filme = {
        .nome    = malloc(2),
        .ano     = malloc(2),
        .diretor = malloc(2)
    };

    strcpy(_filme.nome, arg1);
    strcpy(_filme.ano, arg2);
    strcpy(_filme.diretor, arg3);

    memcpy(filme, &_filme, sizeof _filme);
}


void carregar(Filme filmes[])
{
    analise(&filmes[0], "E o Vento Levou", "1939", "Victor");
    analise(&filmes[1], "teste", "998", "bar");
    analise(&filmes[2], "Os Passaros", "1963", "Alfred Hitchcock");
}

int main()
{
    Filme filmes[1000];

    carregar(filmes);

    printf("\nmain:\n");

    printf("- Nome:    %s\n", filmes[0].nome);
    printf("- Ano:     %s\n", filmes[0].ano);
    printf("- Diretor: %s\n", filmes[0].diretor);

    printf("----------------\n");

    printf("- Nome:    %s\n", filmes[1].nome);
    printf("- Ano:     %s\n", filmes[1].ano);
    printf("- Diretor: %s\n", filmes[1].diretor);

    printf("----------------\n");

    printf("- Nome:    %s\n", filmes[2].nome);
    printf("- Ano:     %s\n", filmes[2].ano);
    printf("- Diretor: %s\n", filmes[2].diretor);

    return 0;
}
```

Notem que executei isto:

```
analise(&filmes[0], "E o Vento Levou", "1939", "Victor");
analise(&filmes[1], "teste", "998", "bar");
analise(&filmes[2], "Os Passaros", "1963", "Alfred Hitchcock");
```

Ao executar o problema a saída é esta:

```
main:
- Nome:    E o Vento Levou
- Ano:     1939Victor
- Diretor: Victor
----------------
- Nome:    teste
- Ano:     998
- Diretor: bar
----------------
- Nome:    Os Passaros
- Ano:     1963Alfred Hitchcock
- Diretor: Alfred Hitchcock
```

Vejam que em "E o Vento Levou" e "Os Passaros" os anos ficaram mesclados com o nome do diretor, `1939Victor` e `1963Alfred Hitchcock`, já no caso do:

```
analise(&filmes[1], "teste", "998", "bar");
```

Tem a saída correta. Eu entendo que deveria fazer o ano com `int`, mas estou aprendendo C e gostaria de entender melhor esta parte da memória, presumo que tenha sido algum **erro de digitação meu**.

Comment: não é só declarar `char ano[5];` dentro do tipo `Filme`?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura porque? Existe motivo, tem explicação para isso? E se os valores são dinamicos, como garantir que não passe estes 4 digitos, por exemplo por algum erro o usuário digitar 99800, como eu faria?

Comment: Acho que o que o @MarceloUchimura estava a tentar dizer é que faltou o espaço para o terminador, que o Maneiro já focou na resposta dele.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento apesar de ser mais comum em código real, deixar as *strings* de tamanho dinâmico fica mais difícil de gerenciar. Para aprender eu recomendo não usar isto de cara. De qualquer forma o ano me parece um caso claro de ser tamanho fixo e não deveria ser alocado fora. O maior motivo para ter uma alocação separada é quando não se sabe o tamanho do objeto, junto com o motivo quando não se sabe o tempo de vida (claro quando se sabe o tamanho e ele é muito grande ou o tempo de vida é mais longo do que pode controlar localmente).

Comment: @Isac era essa a explicação que faltava, pessoalmente acho legal as pessoas virem aqui e dizer, "faz XYZ", mas sem explicar as motivações disto fica complicado determinar o porque e aprender. Afinal não estamos buscando "apenas fazer um código funcionar", estamos buscando aprender de verdade. Tem muito código que funciona, mas não significa que estejam corretos.

Comment: Concordo a 100% consigo, e é sempre o que eu tento fazer. Evitar ao máximo promover o copy paste cego de "coisas que funcionam". Tanto que já houve perguntas que respondi com 2 ou 3 repostas de código a funcionar, e que apenas respondi para explicar o problema, para que a pessoa possa de facto perceber onde errou e melhorar no futuro

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, aprendeu o porquê do `[5]` agora??

Comment: @MarceloUchimura acho que já esta bem óbvio que sim. E o problema de soltar comentários "faça XYZ" sem explicar os motivos, já aprendeu o porque isto [não é bom para a comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303948/strcpy-esta-mesclando-formato-num%c3%a9rico-com-outros-chars?noredirect=1#comment616912_303948)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não é bom para a comunidade ou não é bom para quem não tem interesse (ou tempo) de pesquisar e quer de mão beijada?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura não tem nada haver com mão beijada, você não tá entendendo, veja meu score, veja o tanto que respondo, veja como procuro tentar ser criterioso, eu não to pedindo código pronto ... esse site não é um fórum de suporte técnico, eu pedi uma orientação sobre como trabalhar com strcpy, ou seja é uma duvida totalmente valida sobre a API de strings do C, você só veio e fez um comentário vago, normal e aceitavel, mas eu indaguei o porque disto o que também é totalmente válido, afinal faça Xyz sem o minimo de explicação complica, ainda mais para quem esta estudando.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, seu score mostra que você tem tempo de sobra pra ficar por aqui.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura uma visão bem preconceituosa sem analise e superficial a sua, falta você olhar para o conteúdo das postagens e saber receber uma critica construtiva ao invés de ficar levando pro lado pessoal e ficar se fazendo de vitima, eu fiz uma indagação totalmente válida para o proposito do site, "por que 5?", simplesmente você poderia ter levado como algo construtivo e ter formulado uma breve explicação, estaríamos de bem, mas esta claro que você esta querendo transformar isto em algum tipo de inquisição baseado em um julgamento seu, totalmente superficial.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78394/discussion-between-marcelo-uchimura-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este código tem alguns problemas.

- Não tem porque usar `malloc()` se a área que a *string* deve ficar já está reservada dentro da estrutura. Até poderia alocar se desejar, e talvez faça sentido para os nomes, mas aí precisa declarar como `const char *` e não `[tamanho]`. Tem que ser bem mais cuidadoso quando faz isso. O que inclusive está vazando memória. Em grande volume isso seria trágico. E alocar apenas 2 caracteres onde precisa de vários também não dá muito certo, é que neste caso coincidentemente funciona.
- Não que seja um problema, mas não vejo motivo para criar uma estrutura local, inicializar seus membros e depois copiar para o *array*. Escreva diretamente no *array*, sem criar nada intermediário, inicializar ou copiar.
- As *strings* possuem um terminador, então precisa reservar espaço para ele. O problema específico que está encontrando é que tem 4 bytes reservados para o ano, então os 4 caracteres do ano são colocados ali, e um 5o. é colocado em seguida. Quando coloca o nome do diretor, o seu primeiro caractere vai em cima do terminador da *string* do ano. Aí quando vai ler o ano ele não tem fim, só finalizaria no fim do nome do diretor, por isso fica tudo junto. Se tivesse 5 bytes, o terminador seria preservado e tudo funcionaria ok.

Assim funciona:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[81];
    char ano[5];
    char diretor[81];
} Filme;

void analise(Filme *filme, const char *arg1, const char *arg2, const char *arg3) {
    strcpy(filme->nome, arg1);
    strcpy(filme->ano, arg2);
    strcpy(filme->diretor, arg3);
}

void carregar(Filme filmes[]) {
    analise(&filmes[0], "E o Vento Levou", "1939", "Victor");
    analise(&filmes[1], "teste", "998", "bar");
    analise(&filmes[2], "Os Passaros", "1963", "Alfred Hitchcock");
}

int main() {
    Filme filmes[1000];
    carregar(filmes);
    printf("\nmain:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("- Nome:    %s\n", filmes[i].nome);
        printf("- Ano:     %s\n", filmes[i].ano);
        printf("- Diretor: %s\n", filmes[i].diretor);
        printf("----------------\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/52yIOe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xfcctytt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StrCpyUse.c).

Comment: Mas supondo que o valor seja dinamico, então acabe passando o "80" em ".nome" por exemplo, talvez então eu deva usar `strcpy_s` para tentar garantir que seja "80"?

Comment: Isto é muito mais seguro, não cheguei entrar nesta questão. Fazer um código pronto pra produção é sempre bem mais difícil que esses exemplos que vemos em livros, blogs, tutoriais e respostas no SO :) Validações são sempre necessárias em tudo, especialmente de dados vindos de fora e serão usando em C.

Comment: Note que o `strcpy_s()` não é obrigatório. Há casos que você pode confiar que a *string* é bem formada. Obviamente (quase) nunca quando vem de fonte externa.

Answer (score 3):

O que ocorre é que o seu `struct` ocupa 164 bytes na memória:

- 80 bytes para o nome, incluindo o terminador nulo;
- 4 bytes para o ano, **você não está considerando o terminador nulo aqui**;
- 80 bytes para o diretor, incluindo o terminador nulo.

O compilador vai atribuir os seguintes deslocamentos para cada um desses campos:

- `nome`: 0 bytes de deslocamento desde o início da `struct` na memória.
- `ano`: 80 bytes de deslocamento desde o início da `struct` na memória.
- `diretor`: 84 bytes de deslocamento desde o início da `struct` na memória.

Assim sendo, se pergarmos o primeiro caso por exemplo, o layout fica assim (onde ∅ é o terminador nulo e □ é lixo, que pode ter qualquer valor):

```
E o Vento Levou∅□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□1939Victor∅□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□
```

Quando você faz isso:

```
printf("- Ano:     %s\n", filmes[0].ano);
```

Em tempo de execução, o código gerado vai carregar o endereço de memória de `filmes`, somar 164×0 para obter `filmes[0]` (164 = `sizeof Filme`, 0 é o índice) e então somar 80 para obter a posição de `filmes[0].ano` (80 é a posição do `ano` dentro do `struct`). Dessa posição ele vai imprimir uma string (devido ao `%s`) que começa nessa posição calculada **e termina no primeiro terminador nulo encontrado**. Ocorre que o ano não tem um terminador nulo, e portanto ele vai acabar invadindo a região de memória subsequente do campo `diretor`.

Além disso, esse código não têm nenhum sentido:

```
Filme _filme = {
    .nome    = malloc(2),
    .ano     = malloc(2),
    .diretor = malloc(2)
};
```

O que você queria provavelmente era isso:

```
void analise(Filme *filme, const char *arg1, const char *arg2, const char *arg3) {
    strcpy(filme->nome, arg1);
    strcpy(filme->ano, arg2);
    strcpy(filme->diretor, arg3);
}
```

Para resolver o seu problema sem usar `int` para o ano, uma possibilidade é mudar o tamanho do campo `ano` para 5. Se os demais campos devem ter no máximo 80 caracteres ao invés de 79, então mude o tamanho deles para 81 a fim de se certificar que o terminador nulo está lá.

Outra alternativa que evita ter que redimensionar o tamanho dos campos é especificar uma tamanho máximo para as strings no `printf`:

```
printf("- Nome:    %.80s\n", filmes[0].nome);
printf("- Ano:     %.4s\n", filmes[0].ano);
printf("- Diretor: %.80s\n", filmes[0].diretor);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação sobre o "lixo", já tinha uma noção sobre isto, mas seu exemplo visual foi muito útil mesmo, ainda sim a solução com printf foge um pouco ao que desejo, não é que não funcione, mas é que  fica um pouco inviável já que eu estava buscando o controle pelos proprios valores do struct, que olhando assim agora até me parece desnecessário fixar o tamanho, ainda sim creio eu que `strcpy_s` seria mais viável para resolver tudo isso. De qualquer forma +1 pela explicação visual.